# Get price without tax in Woocommerce rest api

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

i query order in woocommerce rest api. Even when set in woocommerce settings to show  prices without tax i dont get price in api without tax only order total with tax and tax value. i know i can calculate it subtracting one from the other (but there can be cent difference) but would like to get also total price without tax in rest api is it possible?

```
 "id": 19664,
    "parent_id": 0,
    "status": "processing",
    "currency": "PLN",
    "version": "8.2.1",
    "prices_include_tax": false,
    "date_created": "2023-11-22T13:37:40",
    "date_modified": "2023-11-22T13:37:40",
    "discount_total": "58.18",
    "discount_tax": "13.38",
    "shipping_total": "0.00",
    "shipping_tax": "0.00",
    "cart_tax": "254.23",
    "total": "1359.57",
    "total_tax": "254.23",
    "customer_id": 2,
    "order_key": "wc_order_XGDAotcSyR3AW",
```

1359.57 it total with tax. Why there is not net price? How can i add it to rest api?